# Java linux printing question

Tags: java, printing, postscript

I have an application that displays JFrame with graphics to be printed. When I run the application from command line, the printing process works fine. However, if this application is invoked by other application, the printing process does not work and the getGraphics() of the PrintJob class returns null.

Anyone have any ideas what might be a reason of this beahavior? I use Red Hat Linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it certainly won't hurt to provide details on your environment: Linux distro, deskto, Java version, Java implementation, Printing System (cups?), ...

Comment: I use Red Hat Linux 5.5, the problem occurs with jdk 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 (haven't tested that with other versions), the printing system is CUPS, the graphics environment is sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment. I don't think the problem is inside the code as it works properly when application is invoked from the command line.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Is it invoked by a service or a process that is not attached to X session ?

I have experimented same issue with Java graphic/print manipulation **if the process isn't attached to a graphical desktop session** (X Server).

Only solution is to run the process attached to a graphical session, I didn't found any other workaround.

Comment: How can I check that? the output of screen -ls while the application is running is "No sockets found...". Can you pls give me an example how I can run it and be sure that it is attached to the graphical desktop session? Thanks

Comment: Simply put: if you run your java process from a gnome/kde/x terminal, your process is attached to a X Session; if your run your process from SSH or from a deamon your process isn't attached to a X Session. You can too check the $DISPLAY environment variable, if the variable is set you are in a X session.

Comment: What is the 'workflow' to launch your process when it fail ? which application are calling your java application and how ?

Comment: In that case, the process is attached to X Session. I run the script which initiates the system.At runtime, one of its componets uses resource file to get the direcotry of another script, which is used to invoke JFrame. After the dir is located,the script is invoked and JFrame appears on the screen with required graphics. I also noticed that it works OK when I'm prining it to a file, but getGraphics() of the PrintJob returns null with attempt to print it normally.Everything works OK when I run it (app with JFrame) separately.Thanks a lot.